# ¿Cómo ordenar un array alfabéticamente usando sort?

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs, objeto, ordenamiento

Estoy intentando ordenar este array de objetos:

```
const paddockType = [
    { id: 1, name: 'PALTOS' },
    { id: 2, name: 'AVELLANOS' },
    { id: 3, name: 'CEREZAS' },
    { id: 4, name: 'NOGALES' },
]

const rta = paddockType.sort((c, d)=> c.name - d.name)

console.log(rta);
```

No entiendo porque no me lo ordena alfabéticamente, ni decreciente ni ascendente. Ahora bien, si lo hago con `id` funciona.

Comment: Usa operadores de comparación `> < <= >=`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No puedes usar directamente una cadena como ordenacion ya que el resultado sera siempre `NaN`:

```js
console.log("a" - "b");
```

Y **NaN** siempre sera interpretado como `false`, `false` a su vez es interpretado como `0`, por lo que al final el ordenamiento siempre va a fallar.

Para que te tome entonces bien la ordenacion deberias convertir la primera letra de cada uno de los nombres a minusculas (para normalizar codigos `ASCII`) y posteriormente restar ambos valores de esta manera:

```js
const paddockType = [
    { id: 1, name: 'PALTOS' },
    { id: 2, name: 'AVELLANOS' },
    { id: 3, name: 'CEREZAS' },
    { id: 4, name: 'NOGALES' },
    
  ]

  const rta = paddockType.sort((c, d)=> c.name.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - d.name.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0))

  console.log(rta);
```

Donde con el metodo `charCodeAt` recogemos el valor numerico del caracter en la pocision `0`.

Comment: muchas gracias.

Comment: `charCodeAt(0)` no va a funcionar si todas los nombres comenzaran con la misma letra. No es para nada la forma correcta de ordenar.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez acabo de caer en cuenta que si, es una mala solucion para esos casos, gracias por hacerme ver el error, que tal si propones otra solucion mas adecuada?, de esa manera tambien veria como corregirlo y el `OP` tambien podra corregirlo en su codigo.

Comment: @Riven ya agregué una forma de hacerlo.

Comment: No me gusta votar negativo a las respuestas, prefiero comentar de lo que hicieron mal y que aprendan de sus errores. Por favor, intenta hacer lo mismo. Considero que eres uno de los mejores de este sitio. No ganamos nada votando negativo en publicaciones que no lo merecen. Por favor, edita tu respuesta para retirar mi voto.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Que tal si editas la primera respuesta desde donde venimos?, asi podre dejarte de nuevo con los votos normales, mi intencion era unicamente que el usuario pudiese aprender por si mismo hechando cabeza, yo por eso normalmente en ese tipo de respuestas simplemente espero incluso hasta un dia entero para dar una respuesta en caso de que el usuario no haya podido,  de esa manera dejo que el usuario desarrolle su logica, es una excelente herramienta para mejorar como programador ;3, mi voto negativo no fue por que hayas hecho una mala respuesta

Comment: @Riven me parece perfecto! Edita tu también esta.

Answer (score 3):

Para ordenar strings de manera alfabética, necesitamos una función que tome dos strings y, según el orden lexicográfico:

- Devuelva 0 si los strings son iguales
- Devuelva 1 si el primer string es mayor que el segundo
- Devuelva -1 si el primer string es menor que el segundo.

Javascript, compara de manera nativa los strings usando el orden lexicográfico, pero tiene en cuenta las mayúsculas y las minúsculas. Si no te importa ese detalle (dado que veo que todo está en mayúscula), puedes implementar algo cómo:

```js
const paddockType = [
    { id: 1, name: 'PALTOS' },
    { id: 2, name: 'AVELLANOS' },
    { id: 3, name: 'CEREZAS' },
    { id: 4, name: 'NOGALES' },
    { id: 5, name: 'AZUCAR' },
    { id: 6, name: 'ARANDANOS' },
]

const rta = paddockType.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.name < b.name) { return -1; }
    if(a.name > b.name) { return 1; }
    return 0;
})


console.log(rta);
```

Esto mismo lo puedes haces insensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas convirtiendo todo a minúsculas:

```js
const paddockType = [
    { id: 1, name: 'PALTOS' },
    { id: 2, name: 'AVELLANOS' },
    { id: 3, name: 'CEREZAS' },
    { id: 4, name: 'NOGALES' },
    { id: 5, name: 'AZUCAR' },
    { id: 6, name: 'ARANDANOS' },
]

const rta = paddockType.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.name.toLowerCase() < b.name.toLowerCase()) { return -1; }
    if(a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase()) { return 1; }
    return 0;
})


console.log(rta);
```

Alternativamente, usando una sintaxis más moderna, podríamos usar [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare):

```js
const paddockType = [
    { id: 1, name: 'PALTOS' },
    { id: 2, name: 'AVELLANOS' },
    { id: 3, name: 'CEREZAS' },
    { id: 4, name: 'NOGALES' },
    { id: 5, name: 'AZUCAR' },
    { id: 6, name: 'ARANDANOS' },
]

const rta = paddockType.sort((a,b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))

console.log(rta);
```

Comment: Ohh muy bien, excelente respuesta amigo.